# Ibm mobilefirst desktopbrowser environment production issue: Missing app authenticity configuration parameters

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

**Getting Error- E FWLSE0059E:** Login into realm 'wl_authenticityLoginModule' failed,When calling adapters which has authsecurity.
My environment is DesktopBrowser.As per other posts i found that solutions provided for mobile environments.
i changed my authenticationConfig.xml by commenting wl_authenticityRealm based on the solutions provided

```
     <customSecurityTest name="AuthSecurityTest">
       <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="AuthRealm"/>
    <!--   <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/> -->
    </customSecurityTest>
```

and added below webContainer tag in **server.xml**

```
            <webContainer com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressLoggingServiceRuntimeExcep="true" invokeFlushAfterService="false" deferServletLoad="false"/>
```

and below is the code in my **application-descriptor.xml**

```
    <desktopBrowser cacheManifest="no-use"/>
```

i regenerated and redeployed .war,adapters,.wlpp in liberty server.But still i am getting mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Application authenticity check is not applicable to Desktop browser environments.

Application Authenticity applies to iOS, Android, Windows Phone Silverlight 8, and Windows 8 Universal environments.

Refer to http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html

Comment: i removed wl_authenticityRealm.i am getting error in adapter calls which are protected by AuthSecurityTest                                                                         .example :<procedure name="" securityTest="AuthSecurityTest"> </procedure>.so what is the solution for that.please suggest..

Comment: Did you redeploy the runtime war after you made the change? I hope you did not edit the file directly

Comment: yes, i redeployed war and all .wlpp .i edited file directly. How can i access secured adapter procedures without decalring wl_authenticityRealm??.

Comment: You should make the changes to authenticationConfig.xml in the studio, and then regenerate the runtime war and finally redeploy the runtime. Once you have the runtime war deployed, do not navigate to the file ( in the filesystem) and edit directly. Changes to authenticationConfig will require runtime redeploy.
Are you using application authenticity feature in your applications? If not , you can remove it

Comment: issue is fixed by changing the customSecurityTest to webSecurityTest.